# Question Regarding Bionomial Distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> **Que:**   $~~$A fair die is rolled 3 times. The conditional probability   of 6 appearing exactly once ,given that  at appeared at least once  equals.

I can solve this question by considering $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ as  uniform discrete probability space ,where $\Omega$ is set of all possible outcomes of roll a fair die 3 times and $\mathcal A=2^{\Omega}$ and using $$ P(A|B)=\frac {P(A\cap B)}{ P(B)}$$

But there is another solution given as.
\begin{align}
P\left (X=1|X\geq 1\right) &= \frac {P(X=1)}{1-P(X=0)}&=\frac {\binom {3}1\cdot (\frac {1}{6})^1 \cdot  (\frac {5}{6})^2}{1- (\frac {5}{6})^3}\\
\end{align}

Now my question is about what kind of approach used in this solution.
i got whole the solution , they used discrete random variable $X$  defined as $\omega \mapsto ~$number of six's. and looking at $\binom {3}1\cdot (\frac {1}{6})^1 \cdot  (\frac {5}{6})^2$ it seems it has to do something with **Bionomial distribution**.for Bionomial distribution i know  it is specific discrete probability measure .

Now  my question is How Bionomial distribution can be used to such a problem?

**Edit**

: Let $(\Omega,2^{\Omega},P)$ be discrete probability space with each single outcome has probability $p$ .Where $\Omega$ is outcomes of certain experiment . Now i am doing same experiment 3 times .so now new space will be $(\Omega^3,2^{\Omega^3},Q).$ Define random variable $X$ on $\Omega^3$ as $\omega \to$ Number of times $r$ for some fixed $r\in \Omega$.

Now i want to calculate $P(X=2)$. which is
$P(X=2)= P\left(\left\{t\in  \Omega^3 : \text{r appears 2 times in t}\right\}\right)$. By different choice we can calculate such a total t  as $$ \binom{3}2 \cdot (|\Omega|-1)$$. and probability
$$ \frac { \binom{3}2 \cdot (|\Omega|-1)}{|\Omega|^3}$$

Now from here where the Bionomial distribution occurs?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you asking how they calculated the numerator?  They used a binomial distribution... as you already noticed.  Are you asking how to use the binomial distribution here?  Well..... with $3$ dice being rolled... that will play the part of $n$.... and with chance of "success" (being rolling a six) as $p=\frac{1}{6}$ and $(1-p)=\frac{5}{6}$... asking about $k=1$ success... you plug in those values into the binomial distribution... $\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

Comment: Are you asking why binomial distribution is a valid choice of a distribution to describe the rolling of dice and asking how many of them came up as a $6$?  Because... each dieroll being or not being a $6$ is its own independent event... each having a chance at success equal to the other attempts... This is *precisely* what binomial distribution is used for.

Comment: @JMoravitz My question is about what is special in this question that we relate it to bionomial distribution?

Comment: "*But there is another solution given as...*"  What do you mean by this?  Those are the same exact things written one after the other... just with more information filled in in the second.  That is not "*another solution*"... that is simply *more information*

Comment: "*What is special in this question that we relate it to binomial distribution*"  The fact that we performed a binomial experiment.  Very simply.

Comment: @JMoravitz  I am not getting why random variable defined as above give something specific distribution.

Comment: @JMoravitz suppose one knows all mathematical definition ( for measure and probability thoery) .then how would i explain this example?

Comment: From wikipedia: "*In probability theory and statistics, the binomial distribution with parameters n and p is the discrete probability distribution of the number of successes in a sequence of n independent experiments, each asking a yes–no question, and each with its own Boolean-valued outcome: success (with probability p) or failure (with probability q=1-p). A single success/failure experiment is also called a Bernoulli trial or Bernoulli experiment, and a sequence of outcomes is called a Bernoulli process; for a single trial, i.e., n=1, the binomial distribution is a Bernoulli distribution.*"

Comment: Here... each die individually will either be, or will not be a $6$.  Each result is independent.  Each has the same probability of success.  The total number of successes then.... matches the definition of what the binomial distribution is used for, and it is thus applicable...  "*Suppose one knows all mathematical definition. 
 How would I explain this example?*"  You wouldn't.  It is trivial.

Comment: @JMoravitz please check edit.